# Need help to understand one line in the proof

Tags: matrices

> **Lemma.**
>   If the matrices $\mathbf{X}$ ($n\times p$ design matrix of full column rank ) and $\mathbf{L}_{2}$ satisfy $\mathbf{L}_{2}^{\prime}\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$ and $\Omega$ is positive definite then
>   $$
> \Omega - \Omega \mathbf{L}_{2}\left(\mathbf{L}_{2}^{\prime}\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{L}_{2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{L}_{2}^{\prime}\Omega=\mathbf{X}\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{\prime}.
> $$
>
> *Proof.*
>   If $\mathbf{X}^{*}=\Omega^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{X}$, a basis for the orthogonal complement of $\mathbb{R}\left(\mathbf{X}^{*}\right)$ is given by the column of $\mathbf{L}_{2}^{*}=\Omega^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{L}_{2}$
>   as $\mathbf{L}_{2}^{\prime*}\mathbf{X}^{*}=\mathbf{L}_{2}^{\prime}\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$.
>   It is well known that the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal
>   complement of $\mathbb{R}\left(\mathbf{W}\right)$ is $\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{W}\left(\mathbf{W}^{\prime}\mathbf{W}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{W}^{\prime}$
>   for matrix $\mathbf{W}$, so that we have
>   $$
> \mathbf{L}_{2}^{*}\left(\mathbf{L}_{2}^{\prime*}\mathbf{L}_{2}^{*}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{L}_{2}^{\prime*}=\mathbf{I}_{n}-\mathbf{X^{*}}\left(\mathbf{X^{*}}^{\prime}\mathbf{X}^{*}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{*\prime},
> $$

I've tough time to understand the left hand side of the last line in the proof. I would highly appreciate if someone explain this to me. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Hint: given a matrix $A$, what is the formula for orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb{R}(A)$?  Now, note that if a vector space is a direct sum of two orthogonal subspaces, then the sum of the orthogonal projections onto each space is the identity map.